# Using DBUS for application monitoring

Tags: python, monitoring, dbus

After moving some time ago from primarily Java to a selection of languages, most notably Python (but also C, C++ and others) I was looking for a good analogy to JMX in order to provide application local and remote application monitoring.

I've been looking at using DBUS to provide this as it has a good selection of language bindings, seems to have some good parallels to what I was used to with JMX and integrates well with the OS.

I've managed to put together some examples of simple usage for the components in our system, using python-dbus, but was struck with how little documentation and viewers/clients exist. I also cannot find any reference to anyone doing something similar, although I'm sure they must exist.

Is what I'm trying to achieve completely bonkers and not a good fit for DBUS - it seems like it would be a good technology to use, but I was wondering whether anyone else is doing what I seek to do?